# clearInterval does not work in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, clearinterval

Here some magic I think, this works perfectly in Chrome but not in Firefox or Opera

```
var initList = setInterval(function(){ 
   if( cache.isAnimating ) return false;
    cache.isAnimating = true;
    aux.navigate( 1, $el, $wrapper, settings, cache ); //slide
   }, 3500) ;
$(document).ready(function(){
   initList = setInterval(function(){   
    if( cache.isAnimating ) return false;
    cache.isAnimating = true;
    aux.navigate( 1, $el, $wrapper, settings, cache );  
   }, 3500) ;
   })
```

on mouseover Firefox does not clearInterval:

```
$("div.ca-wrapper").mouseover(function(){
   clearInterval(initList);
   }).mouseout(function(){
     initList = setInterval(function(){     
     if( cache.isAnimating ) return false;
      cache.isAnimating = true;
      aux.navigate( 1, $el, $wrapper, settings, cache );    
     }, 3500) ;
})
```

any suggestions?

Comment: Do it with mouseenter and mouseleave events instead. And get rid of the first setInterval before .ready(). You don't need it. If you need the global variable leave just `var initList`. That's enough.

Comment: this makes code work in FF but in Chrome doesnt, function initiates only once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not redeclare same variable (initList) twice. Use an unique name for each interval.

Maybe, this is what you are lookig for:

```
var initList2, initList1 = setInterval(function () {
    if (cache.isAnimating) return false;
    cache.isAnimating = true;
    aux.navigate(1, $el, $wrapper, settings, cache); //slide
}, 3500);
$(document).ready(function () {
    initList2 = setInterval(function () {
        if (cache.isAnimating) return false;
        cache.isAnimating = true;
        aux.navigate(1, $el, $wrapper, settings, cache);
    }, 3500);
})

$("div.ca-wrapper").mouseover(function () {
    clearInterval(initList1);
    clearInterval(initList2);
}).mouseout(function () {
    initList2 = setInterval(function () {
        if (cache.isAnimating) return false;
        cache.isAnimating = true;
        aux.navigate(1, $el, $wrapper, settings, cache);
    }, 3500);
})
```

But using your original code, as setInterval returns an integer, you could use this too:

**don't use that**

quoting **Boris Zbarsky**

> There is no guarantee that setInterval returns consecutive integers
>   (and in fact in some cases it does not), so the "subtract one"
>   approach is not all that great...

```
var initList = setInterval(function () {
    if (cache.isAnimating) return false;
    cache.isAnimating = true;
    aux.navigate(1, $el, $wrapper, settings, cache); //slide
}, 3500);
$(document).ready(function () {
    initList = setInterval(function () {
        if (cache.isAnimating) return false;
        cache.isAnimating = true;
        aux.navigate(1, $el, $wrapper, settings, cache);
    }, 3500);
})

$("div.ca-wrapper").mouseover(function () {
    clearInterval(initList);
    clearInterval(initList - 1); // HERE, we are clearing the previous interval 
}).mouseout(function () {
    initList = setInterval(function () {
        if (cache.isAnimating) return false;
        cache.isAnimating = true;
        aux.navigate(1, $el, $wrapper, settings, cache);
    }, 3500);
})
```

Comment: There is no guarantee that setInterval returns consecutive integers (and in fact in some cases it does not), so the "subtract one" approach is not all that great...

Comment: @BorisZbarsky true, could give headhaches for sure

Answer (score 1):

I think the `setInterval` call before `ready` is not required

```
function doSomething(){
    if( cache.isAnimating ) return false;
    cache.isAnimating = true;
    aux.navigate( 1, $el, $wrapper, settings, cache );  
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    initList = setInterval(doSomething, 3500) ;
});

$("div.ca-wrapper").mouseenter(function(){
    clearInterval(initList);
}).mouseleave(function(){
    initList = setInterval(doSomething, 3500) ;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the first setInterval? Also, I've DRY-ed up your code a bit.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var initList = null;
  setInit();

  $("div.ca-wrapper").mouseover(function(){
    clearInterval(initList);
  }).mouseout(function(){
    setInit();
  });
})

function setInit() {
  initList = setInterval(function(){   
    if( cache.isAnimating ) return false;
    cache.isAnimating = true;
    aux.navigate( 1, $el, $wrapper, settings, cache );  
  }, 3500);
}
```